# Check list for strings using string?

Tags: string, lisp, racket

Hi I am having a little trouble testing a list to see if the list contains only strings. I am reading the documentation 2.3(Iterations, and Recursion) + 3.12 (Conditionals) and I can't quite seem to work lists in the way that I want.

I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible,

```
(define (strings-only? lst)
  [cond
    [(empty? lst) true]
    [else (string?(first lst))
          (string?(rest lst))]])
```

What I assume this does is first checks the list (lst) to see if it's empty.
Then it checks the first variable of the list to see if its a string, then checks the rest. When I put in

```
(define a (list "This" "that"))
```

It pops back that the test is false. I feel like the problem is with the way I'm trying to iterate through the list with first/rest. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, what language is this?

Comment: is that pseudo-lisp? are you sure you tagged this right?

Comment: Looks like lisp to me.

Comment: its Dr.Racket, sorry I swear I typed that in but I didn't!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `else` clause:

```
[else (string? (first lst))
      (string? (rest lst))]
```

1) You have two predicate calls that both return some boolean value, but you aren't connecting them in any way. You want to know if *all* elements in the list are strings, so what boolean operator (`and`, `or`, etc.) would fit best here?

2) `(string? (rest lst))` is going to return false every time, because `rest` returns a list, not a string. To actually make this a recursive function, you want to call `strings-only?` again with the `rest` of the `lst`.

---

In summary:

```
(define (strings-only? lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) true]
    [else (___ (string? (first lst))
               (strings-only? (rest lst)))]))
```

Fill in the blank with the boolean operator that makes the most sense here.

Comment: Wow, thanks. So for anyone else with this issue. ಠ_ಠ has essentially turned this into head(?) recursion by calling my strings-only? throughout the rest of the list.
The blank should be filled in with an and, as both the conditions I wrote were intended to be met in order to get the boolean value I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built in [andmap](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._andmap%29%29) function to accomplish this

```
(define (strings-only? lst)
  (andmap string? lst))
```

Comment: Though, in the Racket universe, it's much more common to use `andmap`, since that's provided by the `racket` language without any imports.

Comment: This is awesome. I'm kicking myself (although both work) for not trying to use the map functions. Can you use the map functions to change the list items in anyway? Such as square everything in a list? Or subtract 2 to every item in a list?

Comment: Never mind discovered the genius of for-each. Thank you for the documentation link.

Comment: Yes. Use map or for-each depending on what you need it to do. map will return a list with each element altered by the function you pass in. for-each will do a similar thing, but it will only return the last result, so it is meant more for logging, printing, etc.

`(for-each (lambda (x) (* x x)) '(1 2 3))` => `9`
`(map (lambda (x) (* x x)) '(1 2 3))` => `(1 4 9)`

Comment: Thanks again for the clarification. I've been messing around with them both for a few hours as of now.